# How can I put multiple lines of text in an NSMenuItem?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmenuitem

I would like to create an `NSMenuItem` with more than one line of text in it, and I'd also like an icon to appear next to both lines of text. I can't use a custom view, because then it wouldn't highlight correctly, and I can't just put a newline in the menu item's title, because the newline gets turned into a space. What should I do?

Answer (score 8):

It turns out that although you can't put a newline in the `title` property of a menu item, you can put a newline in the `attributedTitle`. Something like this will work:

```
item.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"line 1\nline 2"];
```